# Sending mails from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES to send mail but before that i have to send verification link to email address which i want to send. Is there any other way to send email like gmail, ymail using `AWS SES`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are in the sandbox mode. You will have to move to production mode to send emails https://sesblog.amazon.com/blog/tag/sandbox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your account is in SES sandbox, you need to manually verify the recipient email addresses before it will allow you to send.

To test this setup you can use the SES Simulator: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html

You can also manually verify your test email addresses by going to

> SES > Identity Management > Email Address > Verify a new Email Address

[image]

When you move out of production, remember to request for your account to come out of sandbox so you can send emails to everyone.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html